# Variant of the geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain me how one computes
$$\sum_{k=1}^n kq^k = \dfrac{nq^{n+2}-(n+1)q^{n+1}+q}{(1-q)^2}$$
and what exactly the derivative has to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let define the following function: $$f:x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^nq^kx^k.$$
Beside, one has:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nkq^kx^{k-1}.$$
Therefore, one gets: $$f'(1)=\sum_{k=1}^nkq^k.$$
But using the formula for the geometric sum, one has: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},f(x)=\frac{1-(qx)^{n+1}}{1-qx}.$$
Hence, one is able to compute explicitely $f'(1)$.

Comment: should be $f'(q)$

Comment: Why do you plug $1$ into $f'$?

Comment: One has: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n kq^kx^{k-1}.$$
If you want to find the sum you have to compute, you must plug $1$ into $f'$.